# Derivative of Least Squares with L2 Norm

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, machine-learning

I'm new to matrix calculus, and I've never really taken derivatives of summations before. Could someone show me how I would get the first order derivative of this?

$J(w)=\frac{1}{2}[\sum_{i=1}^{m}(w^Tx^{(i)}-y^{(i)})^2]+\lambda||w||_2^2$

Thanks!

Comment: You may check out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzxYlbK2c7E&list=PLA89DCFA6ADACE599

Comment: What are $x^{(i)}$s and $y^{(i)}$s? Are they vectors, scalar...?

Comment: @Jacky Chong Sorry I was going to add that information, but I forgot. x^(i) and y^(i) are vectors.

Comment: Also, include what $w$ is? If $w$ is a matrix then you should include what $\|w\|$ means.

Comment: w is a matrix, and ||w|| is L2 norm

Answer (score 1):

Our cost function is given by

$$J(\boldsymbol{w})=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n-{y}_n \right]^2+\lambda\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{w}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n-{y}_n \right]^T\left[\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n-{y}_n \right]+\lambda\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{w}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[\boldsymbol{x}^T_n\boldsymbol{w}^{}\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n-y_n\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n-\boldsymbol{x}^T_n\boldsymbol{w}y_n+y^2_n\right]+\lambda\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{w}$$

Now, think of $\boldsymbol{w}$ as if it were a scalar and calculate the total derivative

$$dJ = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[\boldsymbol{x}^T_nd\boldsymbol{w}^{}\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n+\boldsymbol{x}^T_n\boldsymbol{w}^{}d\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n-y_nd\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n-\boldsymbol{x}^T_nd\boldsymbol{w}y_n\right]+\lambda d\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{w} + \lambda \boldsymbol{w}^Td\boldsymbol{w}$$
$$= \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[\boldsymbol{x}^T_nd\boldsymbol{w}^{}\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n+\boldsymbol{x}^T_n\boldsymbol{w}^{}d\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n-2y_nd\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n\right]+2\lambda d\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{w}.$$
I used the product rule for the total derivative. Note, that the transpose of a scalar is scalar. I used this to combine the last terms. Now, we note that

$$\boldsymbol{x}^T_nd\boldsymbol{w}^{}\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n=d\boldsymbol{w}^{T}\boldsymbol{x}_n\boldsymbol{x}^T_n\boldsymbol{w}^{}$$

and

$$\boldsymbol{x}^T_n\boldsymbol{w}^{}d\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n=\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n\boldsymbol{x}_n^Td\boldsymbol{w}^{}=d\boldsymbol{w}^{T}\boldsymbol{x}_n\boldsymbol{x}^T_n\boldsymbol{w}^{}$$ becaue both terms are scalars. Because of these observations we can rewrite the total derivate as

$$dJ = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[2d\boldsymbol{w}^{T}\boldsymbol{x}_n\boldsymbol{x}^T_n\boldsymbol{w}^{}-2y_nd\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{x}_n\right]+2\lambda d\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{w}.$$

Factoring $d\boldsymbol{w}^T$ results in.

$$dJ =d\boldsymbol{w}^{T}\left[\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[2\boldsymbol{x}_n\boldsymbol{x}^T_n\boldsymbol{w}^{}-2y_n\boldsymbol{x}_n\right]+2\lambda \boldsymbol{w}\right].$$

The expression in the bracket on the right hand side is the Gradient of $J$ with respect to $\boldsymbol{w}$. Setting the gradient to zero and solving for $\boldsymbol{w}$ results in an estimate $\boldsymbol{\hat{w}}$ for $\boldsymbol{w}$

$$\boldsymbol{\hat{w}}=\left[\sum_{n=1}^{N}\boldsymbol{x}_n\boldsymbol{x}^T_n + 2\lambda\boldsymbol{I} \right]^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^{N}y_n\boldsymbol{x}_n.$$